# Clear the text style of the Element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, strikethrough, text-decorations, text-styling

I need to clear the text decoration property of the element using java script.

Currently I am setting text decoration property of element to 'line-through'. In some point of time i need to undo the strike process.

How to reset the text decoration property using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

**HTML**

```
<p id="a">Some text</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p{text-decoration:line-through;}
```

**js**

```
var p = document.getElementById('a')
p.style.textDecoration = 'none';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/nVeGB/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript: `document.getElementById(element_id).style.textDecoration = "none"`

jQuery: `$('#element_id').css("text-decoration", "none");`

Answer (score 0):

setting text-decoration to none actually is a bit worser then setting text-decoration to "".
    $("div").css("text-decoration", "")

The difference is that by setting to empty string you actually removing js-setted property.
Say, you element has `text-decoration: "underline"` initially (in css, before you've set the value using jQuery). Setting it to "none" will be wrong. Removing the property will be nice.

Answer (score -1):

set the text decoration to none

or with 
`document.getElementById(divID).style.removeAttribute("textDecoration",false)` you can remove the textDecoration form the style (works in IE )

Comment: textDecoration is not an attribute